# What does this error message mean exactly?

Tags: windows-10

Recently installed Ubuntu on windows, and all was going ok. Was doing a college assignment and tried copying the file /etc/passwd to the home directory as user. Seemed to not do anything. Next time I tried to start the app I get the following:

```
-sh: 6: export: Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2018.817.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program: bad variable name
```

Any help would be appreciated either way :)

Answer (score 2):

Your script has an error; it can't handle space (' ') between characters in the path.

So, "/mnt/C/Program Files/Whatever/Comes/Next" got split up as /mnt/C/Program and then Files/Whatever/Comes/Next and together they broke the script.

Try to fix the script.

Comment: I'll rather say, script tried to handle the filename and due to space in filename, script thought it is an argument.

Comment: @Kulfy Since we know the command that broke is export, so we know the statement was going something like export VAR1=/some/variable/that/resolves/in/a/path ; but since there is a space, export expects the later part to be a variable name, and a variable name cannot have / in it; thus the error message, bad variable name.